# HttpRequest Some Special characters are not encoded properly

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a windows service that posts data to a web service. It either sends a PUT or POST request depending on the data. The problem that I am facing is that some special characters are not getting sent properly in the POST request although they are sent properly in the PUT request.

Here is my code.

```
protected void InitializeRequest(String url, String method)
        {
            _Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
            _Request.Method = method;
            _Request.Accept = Settings.AcceptHeader;
            _Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", Settings.AuthorizationHeader);
        }


public void SendData(String json)
{

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

                _Request.ContentType = "application/json";

                _Request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

                try
                {
                    Stream dataStream = _Request.GetRequestStream();
                    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                    dataStream.Close();

                    var response = (HttpWebResponse)_Request.GetResponse();
                    bierResponse = ParseResponse(response);
                    response.Close();
                }
}
```

As you can see I am using the same method for POST and PUT the only difference is the InitializeRequest method which sets the _Request.Method property differently.

The data that I am trying to post contains this string **æøåÆØÅ** which gets transmitted properly for PUT request but gets messed up on POST.

My gut feeling is that the .Net framework handles these in different ways but I have no way to confirm that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys for keeping this posted. The problem was identified and the problem was not at our end. Rather the service to which we were posting was not properly de-serializing the code and when they looked deeper it was identified to be their issue.

Thank you @harshit for your feedback and answer!

Answer (score 0):

In order to post special characters you can try ,

1)string strVar=HttpUtility.UrlEncode(json)

2)string strVar2=Server.HtmlEncode(json)

and then encode the json data.

The thing is , 1st will work on facebook but not on Twitter .So you can try each of above method and check whether it works or not.